# How can multiple classes call one method that takes an instance of the calling class as a parameter?

Tags: java, android, generics, parameter-passing

I want all my other objects to be able to call one common method. What should my shared method type signature for parameters look like?

```
public class appSocket{
    public appSocket appSocket(TYPE genericInstance){
        // Do something with genericInstance here
    }
}
```

In other words, what should "TYPE" look like?

Comment: Probably what you want is possible. But your question is very unclear. Do you want to get the passed object's class? Then `genericInstance.getClass()` is your friend. Do you want your objects have a common method that can be called? Then create an interface with that method and let your classes implement this interface. Besides that you must then adjust your method signature to have a parameter of that interface type.

Comment: off-topic comment, but don't name your classes with names which are already in use by Java like `Socket`.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify this, so thank you for your comment :) I want my objects to have a common method that can be called. The issue with the interface is that they will need to implement almost exactly the same thing, which is redundant code. The problem with extending is Java's safe-measure against the diamond which doesn't allow you to extend more than one class. Thus, I'm stuck with how I can call the same method for two classes without inheritance.

Comment: Well ... Interfaces? Redundant code? Diamond? Inheritance? Your are really confusing the things. I suggest some serious tutorials. For now, let me explain that an interface is the obvious mechanism that suits your needs.

Comment: I apologize. I guess what I meant to say was that an interface does not directly implement anything. Thus, the implementing class of the interface will need to implement it. If many classes are implementing an interface in the exact same way, then you run into the same problem of redundant code.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding interfaces. Is it possible for you to give a default implementation in an interface?

Comment: I think I will write an answer with some mechanism that I think you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: You keep saying "generic" but don't have any generics anywhere. Actually filling in some of that might get you a useful answer.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, chrylis. I actually don't know how to write the type signature of a generic. Seelenvirtuose, thank you, I look forward to your mechanism.

Comment: Sorry, the questino is already closed.

Comment: May I ask you to write me a message of a solution please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a bit confused.  This just corresponds to the current object.  There is no reason to ever say someObject.this.foo().  You'd just say someObject.foo().  You just pass in the object.

Comment: Yes you're right. Let me edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, you just need to make the function take a Context as a parameter, and pass this into it when you call it from your Activity.  I think you've just confused yourself a bit.  But its completely legit to pass this as a parameter to a function.

Comment: I agree. I think "this" can be passed as a parameter into a function. However, what should the type signature of the function receiving the generic class instance be? Should it be Object? Object<T>? I can't name it one specific class because I wouldn't be able to use it with others.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it.  In your code as written, Context in order to call getSharedPreferences.  Object<T> makes no sense because Object isn't a generic.  Object works if you only want to call Object methods like .equals or .toString.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. I have further clarified the question to which specific methods I want it to work with. It is at the very end of the question. :)

Comment: Actually with the 3 example functions you give I have no idea what you're trying to do.  I don't know of any class that has all 3 of those functions.  I think you probably have a major architecture issue and need to back up and think things through.

Comment: Yeah you may be right. As I am running out of time, I will need a quick solution. It's for an android project and these methods are android specific.